# Unlink the Touch Bar API?

Tags: macos, macbookpro-touch-bar

Apple has rejected my app by the following reason:

> Your app links against the Touch Bar APIs but does not appear to include Touch Bar functionality.
>
> If your app does include Touch Bar functionality, please respond to this message in Resolution Center with steps on how to locate it within your app.
>
> If you do not intend to use Touch Bar, please unlink the Touch Bar APIs and submit an updated binary for review.

How can I disable the Touch Bar APIs?

Comment: Got the same message from iTunes Connect, but I know I haven't referenced touch bar. Do you use Xcode 9? Might be something with that. I was able to just submit the same version and just comment that it's not included.

Comment: Yes, I used Xcode 9 GM.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well, upon `grep` using

```
grep -nrIi "touchbar" .
```

`grep` results showed `XCode 9` added `allowsCharacterPickerTouchBarItem="NO"` this to `textfield` in `xib`.

Changing this

```
<textField horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="750" allowsCharacterPickerTouchBarItem="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aaa-bb-ccc">
```

to following solved the problem for me.

```
<textField horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="750" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aaa-bb-ccc">
```